# Openapi 3.0: does 'allOf' make the properties of schemas required if the schema is having single property?

Tags: yaml, openapi, swagger-editor

I am having following schemas defined in 'components' section of my openApi 3.0:

```
schema1:
   required:
      - prop1
      - prop2
      - prop3
   properties:
      prop1
      prop2
      prop3
```

```
schema2:
   required:
      - prop4
      - prop5
      - prop6
   properties:
      prop4
      prop5
      prop6
```

now there is another schema performing 'anyOf' operation on above 2 schemas as

```
schema3:
   anyOf:
     - $ref: '#/components/schema1'
     - $ref: '#/components/schema2'
```

And I have another schema with a single property as

```
schema4:
   properties:
      prop7
```

Now my question is If I perform allOf on schema3 and schema4 in schema5 then will the property7 become a required property? If yes then how to keep property7 optional in schema5.

Schema5 is as:

```
schema5:
   allOf:
     - $ref: '#/components/schema3'
     - $ref: '#/components/schema4'
```

Comment: for schema5, what are the possible values? schema1, schema2 or schema4 or what is expected schema5 to look like?

Comment: @SamiAkkawi Schema5 will be having either of (all of prop1,2,3) or (all of prop4,5,6) along with prop7 which is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the property7 become a required property?

No - because `property7` is not listed in the `required` list anywhere in your schemas.